CarPlay Stream MP3 with netmaui not showing info playing
I'm doing an IOS App with net.MAUI and i would like to reproduce mp3 audio from url.
I'm doing this with this code...
   private async void PlayMp3(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (isPlaying)
            {
                player.Pause();
                player.Dispose();
            }

            AVPlayerItem item = new AVPlayerItem(new NSUrl(fileName));
            player = AVPlayer.FromPlayerItem(item);
            player.Play();
            isPlaying = true;

            
            var trackDuration = item.Asset.Duration.Seconds;
            var trackTitle = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

            var nowPlayingInfo = new MPNowPlayingInfo()
            {
                Title = trackTitle,
                AlbumTitle = "Album Name",  
                Artist = "Test Artist",
                PlaybackDuration = trackDuration,   
                ElapsedPlaybackTime = 0,            
                PlaybackRate = 1.0                  
            };

           
            MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.DefaultCenter.NowPlaying = nowPlayingInfo;

            
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {
                if (isPlaying)
                {
                    nowPlayingInfo.ElapsedPlaybackTime = player.CurrentTime.Seconds;
                    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.DefaultCenter.NowPlaying = nowPlayingInfo;
                }
                return isPlaying;  // Continua fino alla fine della riproduzione
            });
            _interfaceController.PushTemplate(CPNowPlayingTemplate.SharedTemplate, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
    }

The code read the mp3, start it and i can hear it... CPNowPlayingTemplate is showing without info and progress bar...
Buttons previous play and next are visible but they don't respond. (but now isn't matter)
I would like to know why my nowPlayingInfo are not showing...
Thanks...
